# Replace two nested for loops with java 8 API

Tags: java, loops, lambda, java-8

I have the following snippet and I wonder if and how it is possible to replace it with Streams/Java 8 API

```
for (State state : states) {
    for (City city : cities) {
        if (state.containsPoint(city.getLocation())) {
            System.out.printf("%30s is part of %-30s\n",
                    city.getName(), state.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, while it's possible to convert such loop with the Stream API, I don't think you gain in readability in this case and I would stick with this for-loop.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. But I was curious how a solution could look like

Comment: @AlexisC. - Makes sense. Like this nested for loop example, are there any general guidelines on when it is better to NOT use lambdas and streams ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Will be something like that:

```
// first loop
states.forEach(state -> { 
    // second loop for filtered elements
    cities.stream().filter(city -> state.containsPoint(city.getLocation())).forEach(city -> { 
        System.out.printf("%30s is part of %-30s\n", city.getName(), state.getName());
    });
});
```

Comment: That was fast. Thanks i will give it a try

Comment: You can omit streaming the `states` and simply use `states.forEach`.