# Alternative to multiple nested for and if blocks

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream, nested-loops

I'm trying to implement a complicated block that I've written using multiple for loops and if conditions to something much less convoluted. The initial code is

```
for(Coll_Monthly_Main monthlyAccount:monthlyList){
        for(Coll_Daily_Main dailyAccount:dailyList){
            if(monthlyAccount.getAccountId().trim().equals(dailyAccount.getAccountId().trim())){
                for(Catg_Monthly monthlyCategory: monthlyAccount.getCatg()){
                    for(Catg_Daily dailyCategory: dailyAccount.getCatg()){
                        if(monthlyCategory.getPriCatId().trim().equals(dailyCategory.getPriCatId().trim())){
                            monthlyCategory.setMthTtl(dailyCategory.getMthTtl());
                            monthlyCategory.setMtd(dailyCategory.getMtd());
                            monthlyCategory.setYtd(dailyCategory.getYtd());

                            for(SecCatDtl_Mthly monthlySecCategory:monthlyCategory.getSecCatDtl()){
                                for(SecCatDtl_Daily dailySecCategory:dailyCategory.getSecCatDtl()){
                                    if(monthlySecCategory.getCatId().trim().equals(dailySecCategory.getCatId().trim())){
                                        monthlySecCategory.setMthTtl(dailySecCategory.getMthTtl());
                                        monthlySecCategory.setMtd(dailySecCategory.getMtd());
                                        monthlySecCategory.setYtd(dailySecCategory.getYtd());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return monthlyList;
```

I've followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376500/replace-two-nested-for-loops-with-java-8-api) and have managed to implement the first level as below:-

```
monthlyList.forEach(coll_mthly->{
        dailyList.stream().filter(coll_daily->coll_mthly.getAccountId().trim().equals(coll_daily.getAccountId().trim()))
        .forEach(catg_mth->coll_mthly.getCatg())->{

        };
    });
```

For the next level of nesting, I need to loop over a nested list and I'm not sure how to proceed about it. I keep getting a syntax error as follows:-
 **Syntax error on tokens, TypeElidedFormalParameter expected instead**

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

**Update:-**
This is how it looks like following Thomas' answer

```
Map<String, Coll_Daily_Main> dailies = dailyList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(cdm -> cdm.getAccountId(), cdm-> cdm) );

    for(Coll_Monthly_Main monthlyAccount : monthlyList) {
        Coll_Daily_Main dailiesForAccount  = dailies.get( monthlyAccount.getAccountId().trim());

          Map<String, Catg_Daily> dailyCatgories=dailiesForAccount.getCatg().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(cv->cv.getPriCatId(), cv->cv));
          for(Catg_Monthly monthlyCategory:monthlyAccount.getCatg()){
              Catg_Daily dailyCategory = dailyCatgories.get(monthlyCategory.getPriCatId().trim());
              if(dailyCategory!=null){
                monthlyCategory.setMthTtl(dailyCategory.getMthTtl());
                monthlyCategory.setMtd(dailyCategory.getMtd());
                monthlyCategory.setYtd(dailyCategory.getYtd());

                Map<String,SecCatDtl_Daily> dailySecCategories=dailyCategory.getSecCatDtl().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(fg->fg.getCatId(), fg->fg));
                for(SecCatDtl_Mthly monthlySecCategory:monthlyCategory.getSecCatDtl()){
                    SecCatDtl_Daily dailySecCategory =dailySecCategories.get(monthlySecCategory.getCatId().trim());
                    if(dailySecCategory!=null){
                    monthlySecCategory.setMthTtl(dailySecCategory.getMthTtl());
                    monthlySecCategory.setMtd(dailySecCategory.getMtd());
                    monthlySecCategory.setYtd(dailySecCategory.getYtd());
                    }
                }
              }
          }
        }
```

Comment: The logic looks iffy. Assuming the `set...()` methods are really "set" methods, then if your innermost loop can match more than one outer loop category then you're overwriting values.  If not, you're wasting a huge amount of time looping over items that are unrelated.  You'd be better off building a map so you can find the ones that match.

Comment: It would probably help if you explained what that behemoth method is trying to do. It's possible all of these nested loops aren't even necessary.

Comment: It's also confusing why `getAccountId` and `getPriCatId` might return strings that might have to be trimmed. Just sanitize it in the class and ensure that will never happen.

Comment: @JimGarrison, the methods are supposed to update metrics and write them to the monthly list. Yes, I'm overwriting values.

Comment: Converting `for` loops to streams is not going to improve your code. Instead, re-think what you're doing. You're doing double nested loops to scan two lists to find matches. Instead, build a map of one of them, so you can do a fast lookup when scanning the other list. You can even do compound keys to do both account and category in a single map.

Comment: @Swapnil Whatever you're doing, nested loops is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: @Michael, I've got two highly nested jsons mapped to different objects (monthly and daily) and I need to pick some attributes from the daily object and set them to the monthly one if the checks are satisfied.

Comment: @Michael, I've added the trims as a precaution because all these values will be coming from a db and I'll map them to an object there's no way to ensure there are no white spaces in the attributes.

Comment: The lesser seen Lisp style of Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the others already stated multiple times it's most likely better to rethink your approach and make it not even more readable but faster as well. One thing that comes to my mind: you have 3 levels that consist of 2 loops and an if to check whether the elements match (by id). Those levels will have O(n*m) complexity.

However, you could try to build a map or multimap (Guava has some) with the id as the key and get it down to O(n + m):

- O(n) for building the map (ideally on on the larger set, i.e. daily)
- O(m) for iterating over the second set (ideally the smaller set, i.e. monthly)
- Lookups should be O(1) so can be ignored

I'm not sure what all those nested levels mean so I only can give an example of what you could do for one level (I'll take the first):

```
//I'm using Google Guava's classes here
SetMultimap<String, Coll_Daily_Main> dailies = ...;//use one that fits your needs

//Iterate over n daily entries and put them into the map which should be O(n)
dailyList.forEach( cdm -> dailies.put( cdm.getAccountId().trim(), cdm ) );

//Iterate over the (smaller) set of monthly entries and do a lookup for the dailies which should be O(m)
for(Coll_Monthly_Main monthlyAccount : monthlyList) {
  Set<Coll_Daily_Main> dailiesForAccount = dailies.get( monthlyAccount.getAccountId().trim() );

  //level done, either go down to the next or try to further straighten it out or optimize
}
```

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that you'd not have to use Guava with Java 8. Though the definition looks a little more awkward using a `Map<String, Set<Coll_Daily_Main>>` isn't that "hard" anymore:

```
 Map<String, Set<String>> dailies = new HashMap<>();
 dailyList.forEach( cdm -> dailies.computeIfAbsent( cdm.getAccountId().trim(), v -> new HashSet<>() ).add( cdm  ) );
```

Note: you could also use collectors to make it a little shorter and in one line. Whether that's easier to read and use is up to debate.

```
Map<String, Set<Daily>> dailies = 
    dailyList.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( cdm -> cdm.getAccountId().trim(), 
                                                       Collectors.toSet() ) );
```

Comment: Indeed. Java 8 isn't just a magic wand you can wave at ugly code to instantly make it readable, idiomatic and fast.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm trying to implement your solution, the other levels of nesting are there because even if I get the matching account I doesn't necessarily have to contain the same categories and sub-categories for that matter. Would you suggest creating another SetMultimap for these levels too?

Comment: @Swapnil that would probably be the easiest way. It looks like you'd only operate on the list for that level/combination anyways (i.e. `monthlyAccount.getCatg()` and `dailyAccount.getCatg()` seem to be valid for the current month and day) so you'd probably not gain much from doing it otherwise. Btw, you dont have to use Guava as with Java 8 using a `Map<String, Set<Coll_Daily_Main>>` would be useable as well - albeit maybe not that pleasing to the eye ;). I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Thomas, I've updated the code following your suggestions, do take a look and let me know if this is how you envisioned it?

Comment: @Swapnil that looks better but I'd assume you want a `Map<String, Set<Coll_Daily_Main>>` instead of `Map<String, Coll_Daily_Main>`, otherwise you'd just be able to have _one_ `Coll_Daily_Main` per account (which seems wrong). Besides that you could do something similar to what Bentaye suggested, i.e. wrap the individual levels (at least levels 2 and 3) with functions that have a meaningful name and then compose them. That way it should be quite easy to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. I'll prune the code further with Bentaye's suggestions.There'll always be just one Daily and Monthly collection pertaining to one account like 1111 has one monthly and its daily, then 2222 has once monthly and daily I just need to ensure that I'm updating the attributes to their counterparts, so won't need a set

Answer (score 2):

- First you need to extract all your if statements in private methods.
- Then you can start to refactor your for statements with lambdas.

You could even declare a static function (called `loop` in the example below) to export your nested loops logic:

```
public class Test {

  public List<Coll_Monthly_Main> runThatThing(List<Coll_Monthly_Main> monthlyList, List<Coll_Daily_Main> dailyList) {

    loop(monthlyList, dailyList, Test::updateMonthlyCategories);

    return monthlyList;
  }

  private static void updateMonthlyCategories(Coll_Monthly_Main monthlyAccount, Coll_Daily_Main dailyAccount) {
    if(monthlyAccount.getAccountId().trim().equals(dailyAccount.getAccountId().trim())){
      loop(monthlyAccount.getCatg(), dailyAccount.getCatg(), Test::updateMonthlyCategory);
    }
  }

  private static void updateMonthlyCategory(Catg_Monthly monthlyCategory, Catg_Daily dailyCategory) {
    if(monthlyCategory.getPriCatId().trim().equals(dailyCategory.getPriCatId().trim())){
      monthlyCategory.setMthTtl(dailyCategory.getMthTtl());
      monthlyCategory.setMtd(dailyCategory.getMtd());
      monthlyCategory.setYtd(dailyCategory.getYtd());

      loop(monthlyCategory.getSecCatDtl(), dailyCategory.getSecCatDtl(), Test::updateMonthlySecondCategory);
    }
  }

  private static void updateMonthlySecondCategory(SecCatDtl_Mthly monthlySecCategory, SecCatDtl_Daily dailySecCategory) {
    if(monthlySecCategory.getCatId().trim().equals(dailySecCategory.getCatId().trim())){
      monthlySecCategory.setMthTtl(dailySecCategory.getMthTtl());
      monthlySecCategory.setMtd(dailySecCategory.getMtd());
      monthlySecCategory.setYtd(dailySecCategory.getYtd());
    }
  }

  // nested loops through list1 and list2 which apply the function `f` to all pairs. 
  //Using a BiConsumer because the f methods we use always return void
  private static <T, U> void loop(List<T> list1, List<U> list2, BiConsumer<T, U> f) {
    list1.forEach(
        element1 -> list2.forEach(
            element2 -> f.accept(element1, element2)
        ));
  }
}
```